# RefreshView in CollectionView Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I am trying to use `RefreshView` in my `CollectionView`, but I have problem.
when I change manually data in my viewmodels, then I try to refresh with pulled down my screen, refresh circle is appear but my data is not updated

Am I missing something?

This is my code

**View**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                 Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfColor}"
                    Margin="10"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="7" RowSpacing="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}"
                            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            HeightRequest="60"
                            WidthRequest="60" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding ColorName}"
                        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                        TextColor="{Binding Color}"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding ColorDesc}"
                        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                        TextColor="{Binding Color}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class ColorCollectionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    const int RefreshDuration = 2;
    bool isRefreshing;

    public bool IsRefreshing
    {
        get
        {
            return isRefreshing;
        }
        set
        {
            isRefreshing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ListColorModel> ListOfColor { get; private set; }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand => new Command(async () => await RefreshDataAsync());

    public ColorCollectionViewModel()
    {
        ListOfColor = new ObservableCollection<ListColorModel>();
        NewData();
    }

    void NewData()
    {
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Hitam", Color = "Black", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Hitam" });
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Coklat", Color = "Brown", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Coklat" });
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Merah", Color = "Red", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Merah" });
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Orange", Color = "Orange", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Orange" });
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Kuning", Color = "Yellow", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Kuning" });
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Hijau", Color = "Green", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Hijau" });
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Biru", Color = "Blue", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Blue" });
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Ungu", Color = "Purple", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Ungu" });
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Abu-Abu", Color = "Gray", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Abu-Abu" });
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Pink", Color = "Pink", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Pink" });

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListOfColor));
    }

    async Task RefreshDataAsync()
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(RefreshDuration));
        IsRefreshing = false;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: you are supposed to refresh/update data inside of `RefreshDataAsync`, updating data i mean changing your ListOfColor ObservableCollection

Comment: RefreshDataAsync does not actually do anything to your data.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Cfun : can u give me example code sir, what must i write down there, 1 stuck 2 days just for it, i have no idea what must i do, i trhy to add NewData(); after IsRefreshing = false;  the data becomes duplicate

Comment: @Jason : I expect, when i change manually data, 
For example i change ColorName = "Pink" to ColorName = "Maroon"
so when i pulled down to refresh, data in interface updated from pink to Maroon, it is possible?

Comment: That's not how it works.  If your model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, changes to the properties should be updated in the UI immediately.  RefreshView is typically used to load more data from a remote source, or to refresh existing data from a remote source.

Comment: @Jason : thanks for ur info sir, i think i misunderstood about how it worked, now i understand how it works, my problem solved, Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pull down the RefreshView command that you bound to `RefreshDataAsync` will execute but you are not changing any data inside of it try with something like:

Only for illustration, it will clear all data and load only one

```
    async Task RefreshDataAsync()
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;
        ListOfColor.clear();
        ListOfColor.Add(new ListColorModel { ColorName = "Pink", Color = "Pink", ColorDesc = "Ini Warna Pink" });
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(RefreshDuration));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListOfColor));
        IsRefreshing = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thx for ur illustration sir, it's really help me to understand how it's work, I misunderstood before, i just call NewData() method; without clear the data, it makes my data duplicated and make mo so confuse, now my problem solved sir thanks, so i can move to next step, learn how to consume api.